# ajax submit form and return uploaded image

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery

I'm trying to return the image that I'm uploading on submit.

The problem is I'm not sure how to load in the upload because it's undefined below.

The image path is also `<img src="user + upload"/>`

Please let me know where to troubleshoot this.

```
var dataString = 'user='+ getuser + '&upload=' + imgupload;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
   $('.lightwindow').hide();
   var findme = $(".empty:first")
   $(findme).removeClass("empty").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("ui-state");
   $(findme).append('<img src="'getuser + imgupload'" width="45" height="60" class="expand"/>')
   }
});
return false;
```

Comment: I believe that the `data` parameter on the success state refers to the output of your PHP code. So you can process it on `process.php` and outputs the filename of your uploaded photo and append it to `$(findme)`

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(data)

Comment: I updated the image path.

Comment: If I put some of this success function on the process.php page will that work via ajax on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't show where you defined `$(findme)` , i'm guessing it should be `$('.findme')` or `$('#findme')`

you need to check to see if the data that is returned from ajax call is actually full and actually accurate.

you need to you F12 developer tools to check for javascript errors - I'd be willing to guess there are a few.

and ..

is `'<img src="'data.upload'"`  is data.upload the actual path of the image??

**update**

start with this..

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     ...
     ...
```

then go into the console and see what is logged - the only way that code will work if `data` is an object looking somthing like

```
....{ "upload" : "mypath/myimage.jpg" , ...... , ...... }
```

you have to have a property defined `upload`

Comment: data.upload is my guess on how to pull the two types of submitted data together.